# auto fill current_user in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql

i have just start with phpmyadmin, i want to auto fill logs that insert/update in database.
i use trigger to do this but it didnt work.
how i do next?

here is my code

[table]

[image: 1]

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `auto_insert_user` 
BEFORE INSERT ON `author` FOR EACH ROW 
set @updateby:=CURRENT_USER
```

update
i try to replace `current_user` by `user()` but it didnt work

Comment: Please read not only the accepted answer, it may be easier to do this using an expression as default value, if your mysql version supports it.

Comment: @Shadow i watch tutorial about it and still cant fint default value for auto fill ```current_user``` . can you show me or give me a key work to find.

Comment: I already gave you a link.